# How do I declare a TField as nullable?

Tags: delphi, null, tdataset

I'm setting up an ADO-based client dataset, and when I try to insert a null value into a TIntegerField, on Post I get `Project raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Non-nullable column cannot be updated to Null'.`

I know I've seen a way to set a TField as nullable before, but I can't remember where or how.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: The field is set to Required = false at design time, and I've verified that it's still false at runtime, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you verified if the db field which this field represents
have a not null constraint?

Comment: hehehehe... That one happened to me so many times... It's one of the first things I verify... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
MyField.Required := False;
```

Answer (score 0):

From help to Delphi 5:

```
property Required: Boolean;
```

but be aware of:

```
property CustomConstraint: String;
```

Also some implementation of classes inherited from TDataSet may add some logic on their own...

Comment: Yeah, apparently that's the case here.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this will help but it sounds familiar. check the properties on the fields of the ado dataset that feeds the cds. i know in d7 the cds internally takes on the readonly property of the provider's dataset regardless of its own readonly setting. the same problem may apply to the required property.